# Python How to extract specified string within [ ] brackets in pandas dataframe and create a new column with boolean values

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pandas, extract

I'm new to programming and would appreciate any of your insights!

I have a data frame like this.

df;

```
            info                Price  
0   [100:Sailing]                $100
1   [150:Boating, 100:Sailing]   $200
2   [200:Surfing]                $300
```

I would like to create new columns with activity names based on information in info column and add 1 in the new column if there is a corresponding name in info column. It is going to look like dataframe below.

```
   Price  Sailing  Boating  Surfing
0   $100       1         0        0
1   $200       1         1        0
2   $300       0         0        1
```

I tried a code blow but did not work..(eventhough this approach works in other columns)

```
df1 = df.info.str.extract(r'(Boating|Sailing|Surfing)',expand=False)
df2 = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df1).astype(int)],axis=1)
```

I have over 10 thousands of data like this so idealy I would like to write a code which automatically extract specified string (like Surfing) in info column, create a new column with the activity name and return 1 or 0 as shown above. I thought that maybe brackets in the data or data type in the dataframe are causing the problem, but I am not sure how to tackle this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed the format of the values in the info column is like a Python list.

```
df1 = df['info'].str[1:-1].str.replace(' ', '').str.get_dummies(',')
df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit(':')[-1], inplace=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1.astype(int)], axis=1)

df2
Out: 
                         info Price  Sailing  Boating  Surfing
0               [100:Sailing]  $100        1        0        0
1  [150:Boating, 100:Sailing]  $200        1        1        0
2               [200:Surfing]  $300        0        0        1
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I could not think about that approach;) As I ran the code, I got an error like this "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas".  The error sounds like values in info column is not string value and I need to somehow change it to run the code..(?) Do you have any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: They can be actual lists I think. Can you try this as the first line `df1 = df['info'].str.join('___').str.get_dummies('___')`

Comment: Wow! It works like a magic! Thank you so much! I realized that `df['info'].str.join('___')` magically deletes brackets in the info column. But I have not figure out how whole this logic works.  Could you elaborate on the role of `.str.join('___')` and `.str.get_dummies('___')`? I really want to understand this.

Comment: There are no brackets actually. You see those brackets only when you print the lists. `str.join(sep)` takes each element of a list, and joins them using the provided separator. So if you have a list `['a'`, 'b', 'c']`, str.join(',') gives you 'a, b, c'. Since str.get_dummies uses a separator to generate columns, this separator should be something that is not seen in the actual strings. If you are sure that there is no comma in the text, you can use comma as well (for both joining and getting dummies).